# How i can make a printeable pdf template with php variables?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, report, ms-office

1- Hi, i'm working with a web app made in codeigniter, and need print reports..
Have any way to make templates in word o some text editor (no css please) for print with my variables?

2- Addicinally need made the same, but with a ID CARD, some idea?

i want a some end template on html or some...

like

```
<h1>This is a simple report made with word or any editor</h1>
<p>CLIENT DATA:<php echo $myphpvariable; ?> </p>
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and add relevant code and errors you are experiencing?  If you are still confused on how to ask questions please check stacks guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="sample">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
            new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');
            new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
    <form class="editor">
      <header>Trainee Extend Letter</header>

    <br>
        <center>
            <textarea id="area1" rows="20" cols="65" > Type your document here </textarea>
```